# Python: Check if Facebook user has granted access to my app. Fails with "HTTP Error 400: Bad Request"

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-permissions

I am trying to determine whether a user has granted access to my application and, if so, which permissions it has. This is NOT during the initial sign-up process, but later when I need to verify that the users hasn't removed permissions.

I run the following:

```
access_token = "users_access_token"; # saved when user signed up using FB
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/permissions/?access_token="+access_token
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

If the user has granted access then the response is a json string with permissions. This is the same that I see if I copy-paste the url into a browser.

However, if the user has NOT granted access (ie removed my app after initial sign-up) then I get an error: "HTTP Error 400: Bad Request". But, if I copy-paste the url into my browser then I get a json string with a proper error message: "The user has not authorized application..." (If I enter a wrong access_token in the browser url then I still get a proper error message "Malformed access token")

So, how can I gracefully check whether user has revoked access to my app? I don't want to get an exception, but rather a proper FB error response. It seems that this should be possible since it works when I copy-paste the url into the browser.

Note that I do not change my code at all. The only thing that changes is whether the user has granted access to the app (so it's not that the url is malformed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTPError` itself contains the info you need, just do this:

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.read())
```

Then it will print out the error message:

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}
```